# Facing issues with Blazor webapp deployed on Netlify

Tags: web-applications, http-headers, blazor, netlify, github-actions

I'm pretty new to web development, I might talk non-sense.
After following some tutorials I've found a way to deploy a Blazor webapp on Netlify.
For that I'm using a DotNet action on Github. It works almost perfectly, here is is the link: https://chefty.netlify.com.
The thing is, my website is blocked by my antivirus (Avast). Page is stuck on "Loading..." blank screen saying "An unhandled error has occurred. Reload".
I ended up looking for solutions and found out that it could come from the fact I'm missing a _headers file.
People were also advising to add a _redirects file.
So I added those to the root of my website, next to index.html:

_headers

```
/*
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

_redirects

```
/* /index.html 200
```

I also used this website https://securityheaders.com to test my url headers and I get a D grade...
When I check my github action workflow those two files are there, in the dist folder I deploy. Then when I dot Inspect element sources on my page, there files are missing, no idea why.
Any help would be much appreciated !

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got [a solution](https://community.netlify.com/t/facing-issues-with-blazor-webapp-deployed-on-netlify/9972/4) from Netlify support engineer.
I had three extra non-printing bytes at the start of the _headers. I removed them and it worked.

To remove extra bytes I used [HxD editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Start HxD as administrator to edit.

Comment: Useful. You may want to add a note about saving the file as plain ASCII, you probably were using the UTF8+BOM format.